# GSConnect remains in notification's applications list

Tags: 18.04, notification, settings

After installing and uninstalling GSConnect, the icon for this app remains in Settings > Notificaftions > Applications (list). Its mildly annoying and I would like to remove it from there; any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: Welcome to ask Ubuntu. Please edit your question and add information about how you installed and how you uninstalled GSConnect?

Comment: GSConnect is a gnome extension. I used the firefox extension to install/uninstall

Comment: Gnome shell extension can be installed both from browser and from the Ubuntu Software (Store) app. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions for more details.